# How to annotate a python method parameter to indicate a numpy array is being passed in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, python-3.8

I can do this in Python 3:

```
def foo(bar: int):
    pass
```

So that `bar` is guaranteed to be an `int`.

Assuming I have a np array like so:

```
bar = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float32)
```

How can I annotate the `foo` method to enforce this type?

Comment: Make sure to read [Do type annotations in Python enforce static type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734029/do-type-annotations-in-python-enforce-static-type-checking). If you want to annotate a numpy array, you can find out what type it is by doing `type(bar)`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I had misunderstood these annotations. Coming from TypeScript I expected this to be enforced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.ndarray` to specify you want an array. I don't think Numpy currently allows you to specify the data type using generics. Note that this only works as of Numpy 1.20.

Numpy 1.20 is available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.20.0rc2/) as a release candidate