# Is there a Pythonic way to type a function parameter to a specific django model object?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, typing

Let's say I have a model like this:

```py
class Foo():
   name = models.CharField()
```

And a function like this:

```py
def update_foo_name(foo_object):
   foo_object.name = "New Name"
```

Is there a way to enforce typing on `update_foo_name()`, so that only a valid object of `Foo` can be passed here?

Ie something like `update_foo_name(foo_object: Foo.objects)`.

Apologies if this has already been asked, and thank you in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a pythonic way should be

```py
class Foo():
    name = models.CharField()
    
    def change_name(self, new_name: str):
        self.name = new_name
        self.save()
```

if you really wanna do it out of Foo scope, in a global function or from a Bar class for example, a way to guarantee is:

```py
class Bar()
   ...

    def method_to_change_foo_name_for_any_reason(self, foo: Foo):
        assert isinstance(foo, Foo), TypeError("Not a Foo object")
        foo.name = "New name that bar gives to foo"
        foo.save()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I've accepted this answer since it also includes the assertion which is definitely what I needed even though I didn't ask explicitly for it.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not do static type checking, [see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734029/do-type-annotations-in-python-enforce-static-type-checking).

---

It means that this:

```
def set_foo_name(foo: Foo):
    foo.name="New Name"
```

**doesn't raise an exception** when you pass in an object of some other type.

You'll have to run `assert isinstance(foo, Foo)` as per Luid's answer.